# How to modify Eloquent relations and pass it to Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I need to modify Eloquent relations (it can be change the value, or shuffle, or remove certain items)

In Controller, you can do this:

```
$question = Question::first();
//$question has a relationship with Answer, therefore I have $question->answers.
$question->answers = $this->modifyAnswers($question->answers);
dd($question->answers) //Worked! Displaying modified Answers

return view('someView', compact($question));
//In the blade file, it's receiving original $question->answers
```

Workaround is by adding new attribute with different name.

```
$question->modifiedAnswers = $this->modifyAnswers($question->answers);
//And blade can access $question->modifiedAnswers
```

But is there any way so that I can modify the value without adding another attribute?

Comment: Try [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: Why dont you use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: No. What I want is to replace the current relations Collection with the modified one. Also, the modified value alrd in the internal attributes array (checked by dd() ) But somehow Blade/Vue shows the original value.

Comment: Did  the answer below solve your issue or are you still needing help?

Comment: Yes. It solves the issue. Altho if there're any other way, that'd be awesome to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, with the method `setRelation($name, $value)`

```
$question = Question::first();

$question->setRelation('answers', $this->modifyAnswers($answers));

dd($question->relationLoaded('answers'));
```

more info here [Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setRelation)